# Spring data query substring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a column called `PAYMENT_REF` that contains value of the following sequence:

```
DBC2020999999999999
```

It will always have the length `19` and starts with `DBC` followed by the year which is this part: `DBC2020`

The following numbers after the year is a sequence number which is `999999999999`.

Basically I need to do a query that find the max value only from the sequence number ignoring the static `DBC` and year `2020`.

Basically when I run the following query on oracle developer ide I get the correct result:

```sql
select MAX(SUBSTR(PAYMENT_REF,7,19))
from PAYMENT p
where PAYMENT_REF is not null;
```

So I tried the following query which looks should get the max value of:

```java
public interface PaymentRepository extends JpaRepository<Payment, String> {


    @Query(" select MAX(SUBSTRING(p.paymentRef,7,19)) from payment p where p.paymentRef is not null")
    int getMaxRefNumber();
}
```

But I get a compilation error cannot resolve symbol: payment, any idea what I a missing here please?

Comment: Try to replace `payment` by `Payment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should correct your query in the following way:

```
@Query("select MAX(SUBSTRING(p.paymentRef, 8, 12)) from Payment p where p.paymentRef is not null")
String getMaxRefNumber();
```

As it is stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#jpql-standardized-functions):

> `SUBSTRING`
>
> Extracts a portion of a string value. The second argument denotes the starting position, *where 1 is the first character of the string. The third (optional) argument denotes the length.*

```
1      8
|      |
DBC2020999999999999
       \          /
         12 chars
```

P.S. To be honest I wasn't able to cast string to number in the hql.

The statement like the following:

```
select MAX( cast(SUBSTRING(p.paymentRef, 8, 12) as long) )
from Payment p where p.paymentRef is not null
```

will not work, the following exception is raced:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery [java.lang.Long] is incompatible with query return type [class java.lang.String]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.resultClassChecking(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:863)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:817)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
```